# Can I pass in a function name or datasource to a T-SQL function or stored procedure as parameter?

Tags: sql-server

Can I pass in a function name or datasource to a T-SQL function or stored procedure as parameter? So as to reuse the function or stored procedure. If possible can show me some examples?

Comment: I posted an answer to passing a proc or function via parameter below.  As for datasources, in what form are you going to pass the datasource?

Comment: datasource as in the name of the table

Comment: Gotcha... just curious if you were thinking of passing an array, or a comma separated list or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it's through an approach known as dynamic sql.  The real question to answer now that you know that is should you.  There are a lot of caveats and dangers to dynamic sql that you need to be aware of if you are going to use that approach.

There's a whole lot of really good info out on the web that can give you more info.  A good place to start is here.  This has been a good guide on the web for some time.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

This is also another good series to read up on.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

To be clear dynamic sql has some very good uses... just be careful and wise.